# Git multiple outputs

Tags: git, push, branch, git-checkout

I have a master and want to have several "outputs" How do I accomplish this.
I've no clue if this is possible with Git.

Please have a look at this example git project:

**Master**

- phpfiles.php
- config.php
- plugins

  - a.php
  - b.php
  - c.php

**Branch A**

- phpfiles.php
- config.php -> is different then the Master
- plugins

  - a.php

**Branch B**

- subfolder1
- subfolder2*

  - phpfiles.php
  - config.php -> is different then the Master
  - plugins

    - c.php

Please note that subfolder2* contains "Master" with additions...

When I change something in phpfiles.php in the Master 
For instance on my local machine I go to Master/phpfiles.php make a change
then apply these commands in terminal:

git status (optional)

git checkout master (optional?)

git add . -A

git commit -m "Made a change"

git push

**For Branch A:**
I go into that folder on the webserver and or local machine:

git checkout Branch A

git pull origin master

--

**For Branch B:**
I go into that folder on the webserver and or local machine:

git checkout Branch B

git pull origin master

Is this the correct workaround to accomplish this?
Any help is much appreciated!

--

**My steps are:**

I've done this, from scratch, created new folder:

git init

git remote add origin https://****@bitbucket.org/***/***.git

git fetch && git checkout BranchB

git merge --strategy=ours origin/master

->I get: Already up-to-date.

ls

->I get:

- subfolder1
- subfolder2

I'll then try to "get" the changed file manually from master which needs to
go in subfolder2 so:

git checkout origin/master -- changed.php

ls

-> I get:

-subfolder1

-subfolder2

-changed.php

Comment: Hi @user3632342 - what do you understand with "different outputs"? What is the problem you'd like to solve?

Comment: Problem is that changes I make in the master need to be done in Branch A & Branch B. At the moment I'm not able to do that with Git (Manual I could do it of course...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If branchA and branchB can be constructed by recipe from master, what you have is multiple makefile targets, not multiple branches.  If `make` is too heavyweight, the [branch-specific includes in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20087076/1290731) might serve.  *Remember that branch names are entirely local, per-repo entities.*  With that setup you can use checkout as a poor-man's-make, with e.g. `checkout -B config-set-A` to reconfigure your current working directory with the new config set.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to push/pull to propagate a change from one branch (`master`) to other branches (`branchA`, `branchB`).
You can use local git operations only. No need to use an upstream remote repo.

You can either:

- [cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the commit you just did in `master` (cherry-pick it to `branchA`, then `branchB`).
  See "[Git and working on multiple branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1340143/6309)"
- merge `master` to the other branches: see "[Merging one change to multiple branches in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7908629/6309)".
  But that assumes you already did a [`git merge --ours`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1295232/6309) *before* committing into `master`

  ```
  git checkout branchA
  git merge --strategy=ours master
  git checkout master
  # do your commit
  git checkout branchA
  git merge master
  ```

That way, the second merge will only include the commit you just did in `master` instead of trying to add everything from `master`.

Comment: @user3632342 sure: after a `git init`, there is no remote registered in the local empty repo you just created, so the `git fetch` can only fails. If you want to initialize the content from a remote repo, you should add its url first `git remote add origin /url/of/remote/repo`. Then git fetch (or rather `git pull origin master` in order to initialize the working tree).

Comment: Ok one more question:
I've done this, from scratch, created new folder:
git init
git remote add origin https://****@bitbucket.org/***/***.git
git fetch && git checkout BranchB
git merge --strategy=ours origin/master
->I get: Already up-to-date.
ls
I get: 
- subfolder1
- subfolder2

I manually get the changed file from master which needs to go in subfolder2:
git checkout origin/master -- changed.php

Comment: @user3632342 first, create local `master` from the remote `master` after your `git fetch` (`git checkout -b master origin/master`). Are `branchA` and `branchB` already present in the BitBucket remote repo?

Comment: Yes A&B are present in remote repo

Comment: @user3632342 then create them locally too before attempting any merge/commit. `git checkout -b branchA origin/branchA`...